# Native Script App build : Issue facing while gradle build

Tags: java, android, gradle, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have created a native script application and trying to build using tns command(tns build android) and facing the below issue:

Project successfully prepared (android)

```
Building project...

Gradle build...

+ setting applicationId

+ applying user-defined configuration from C:\project_repo\helper_mobile_app\helper\app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle

Applying settings from C:\project_repo\helper_mobile_app\helper\app\App_Resources\Android\settings.json

+ adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector

+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\project_repo\helper_mobile_app\helper\node_modules\tns-core-modules-widgets\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder - protected system package 'java.lang'

at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkClassName(ClassLoader.java:292)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:334)

at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:727)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:95)

at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1182)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:602)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)

at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:1220)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)

at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.GetInterfaceNames.generateInterfaceNames(GetInterfaceNames.java:59)

at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.GetInterfaceNames.generateInterfaceFile(GetInterfaceNames.java:32)

at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:42)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the java class not found error to calander plugin,
This worked well for me.

delete `node_modules`, `platforms`, `hooks` folders and `package-lock.json` file
run

```
npm i
```

rebuild the project ->

```
tns run android
```

or

```
tns build android
```